# Approaching a multivariate regression problem with multiple observations over days

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, prediction, multivariate-regression

Assume for every $Y_{n*1}$, there is a covariate matrix $X_{n*p}$. The goal is to predict $Y'_{n*1}$ when new $X'_{n*p}$ becomes available.

What complicates the matter is that I have $k$, let's say 20, examples of such $X,Y$ pairs in my training data set. If there was only 1, then I could do a Principal components regression, or Random forest, etc. But I am having a hard time understanding how to approach this problem. If I concatenate them, I would get  $X_{(k*n)*p}$ and $Y_{(k*n)*1}$, but this won't be useful for predicting $Y'$ when new $X'_{n*p}$ becomes available.

Ideally, I would like to reduce $X_{n*p}$ to a lower dimension, and use the resultant for regression.

Comment: Why not concatenate them and then add an a variable for day, where day=1, 2, . . . k=20?

Comment: Let's say I want to do PCR. I think adding the "day" column itself would be problematic, but ignore that for now. If I extract the pcs of $X_{k*n*p}$, would I be able to use these for a matrix of $X_{n*p}$ ?

Comment: Of course.  using the principle components as inputs to your regression is fine.  In fact, the nice thing about this is that you are assured that the inputs are orthogonal to one another.  The only problem is you might lose interpretability, but if you sole goal is prediction, then you may not care about interpreting your regression coefficients.